# Redactor image upload doesn't work

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, redactor

Website with redactor running on subdomain. It reports errors:
chmod() - failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
and move_uploaded_file() - failed to open stream: No such file or directory. 
All file permissions are set right. Here is code of image upload:

```
// files storage folder
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Picks/Redactor/';

$_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg'
|| $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)
{
    // setting file's mysterious name
    $filename = md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';
    $file = $dir.$filename;

    // copying
    chmod($dir, 777);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);

    // displaying file
 $array = array(
  'filelink' => 'Picks/Redactor/'.$filename
 );

 echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this has nothing to do with Redactor.

You get this error most likly, because the directory does not exist. chmod does not create it.

Try this

```
if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    //dir, rights, recursive
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true); //Maybe we need not that much permissions...
}
```

Are you sure, dir is that, what you think?

```
var_dump($dir);
```

Not know much about linux, but at least under windows, if we want to grant (directory) rights, the executing script (not includes, the real file you call in Browser) needs the same rights.

Site node: We should never grant execution rights for files, that comes from user. Also note, the mimetype mustn't be accurate. Special for Images, [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesize.php) would be more relyable.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is a simplified example, which doesn't cover security of uploaded images.
// This example just demonstrate the logic behind the process.


// files storage folder
$dir = 'uploads/data/'; // or use '../uploads/data/' but not use '/uploads/data/'

$_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
{
    // setting file's mysterious name
    $filename = md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';
    $file = $dir.$filename;

    // copying
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);

    $array = array(
        'filelink' => "/".$dir.$filename
    );

    echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
    //print_r($_FILES['file']);

}
```